# DropDown menu on value change doesn't work after load scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

So the dropdown menu on value change is no longer working after loading to new scene, google for a very long time. Resetting the input, and event system. Still no luck.

Comment: Likely because the object it was calling was recycled when the scene was loaded?

Comment: so the problem is, when i reload the scene everything on the On Value Change is still here, it just doesn't work. But if I delete it and add the same thing back in, it then work.

Comment: Then I create another script to add the listener through scripting, but it doesn't work. Only work in changing it in the inspector.